# How can my base constructor access the derived instance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

I have a base class `Animal` and a derived class `Lion`. Each animal should hold a reference to the King of the Jungle, which is always a lion. So a read-only property `Lion : KingOfTheJungle` is added in the base class. This property is initialized in the `Animal`'s constructor.

The idea is to create first the `Lion` object, and then pass a reference of it to the constructors of all other animals. The Jungle has only one lion, so when the lion is constructed should recognize itself as the King of the Jungle. The problem is that I can't create the `Lion`, because I get a compile time error when I pass `this` as a parameter to `base()`:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; }

    public Animal(Lion theKing)
    {
        KingOfTheJungle = theKing;
    }
}

class Lion : Animal
{
    public Lion() : base(this) // Error CS0027
    {
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Error CS0027 Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

Searching for a workaround I ended up passing `null` instead of `this` in the `Lion`'s constructor, and interpeting the `null` as `this` in the `Animal`'s constructor:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; }

    public Animal(Lion theKing)
    {
        KingOfTheJungle = theKing ?? (Lion)this; // OK, but unsafe
    }
}

class Lion : Animal
{
    public Lion() : base(null) // OK, but not expressive
    {
    }
}
```

I don't like this workaround though, because it is neither expressive nor type-safe. Is there any safer or at least more elegant way to do the same thing?

**Note:** I want to keep the property `KingOfTheJungle` read-only, without a `protected` setter. The animals shouldn't be able to change this property after initialization.

Comment: @mjwills I tried it, and it's a workable solution. I am not totally enthusiastic about it though, because it adds two responsibilities to each derived class. 1) to add the line `public override Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; }` and 2) To assign the property `KingOfTheJungle` in its constructor. The (2) gives me the anxiety that I might forget it, since it is not enforced by the compiler, and I have a bunch of derived classes to implement.

Comment: IMHO, this requirement needs to be pushed up a level. In other words, if there's a hard requirement that a jungle has a single lion that is the king and no other animal can exist without knowing its king, then the existence of that jungle requires a lion as a param on construction or a constraint exists that no animal can be added to a jungle without a king. A base class knowing about its children is a design disaster; there is no solution for that.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I know a framework for building robust OOP applications where the base class knows about its descendants. The type of the descendant is passed as a type parameter, like this: `public class Customer : BusinessBase<Customer>` ([source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=6OkTWMLg71IC&pg=PA140)). It is Rockford Lhotka's [CSLA .NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_Scalable_Logical_Architecture) framework. Does your criticism apply to this as well?

Comment: But the example doesn't know about the descendant as it is a generic. That is different than depending, *explicitly* on the *actual* type.

Comment: When an `Animal` knows that, without a doubt, a descendant exists (*always*); that is a circular dependency. The descendant (Lion) cannot exist without its parent  (Animal) and the Animal cannot exist without a King (aka Lion); that's not a great way to design things.\

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils thanks for your answer. Personally I don't have a strong opinion about this, but I was interested to hear your point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `KingOfTheJungle` could be a `virtual` (or `abstract`) readonly property in the base class. Then override it in the inheriting classes.

Something along the lines of:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; }    
}

class Lion : Animal
{
    public override Lion KingOfTheJungle
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced my workaround with this solution because it is clearly more robust. Eventually though I should probably follow Peter Duniho's advice and change my design by introducing a `Jungle` class. The `Jungle` object will hold a reference to the King `Lion`, and all `Animal`s will hold a reference to the `Jungle`. This is a more reasonable design, and as a bonus it will make my current problem disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is with a `static` property:

```
public static Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; } = new Lion();
```

This solves several problems:

- Non-deterministic crowning of the king. With this approach, there is always a king.
- Too many kings. With this approach, there is always exactly *one* `Lion` that is king. Any other `Lion` instances are just plain `Lion`.
- Different `Animal` instances consider different `Lion` instances their king, depending on which `Lion` was instantiated at what time.
- Many copies of the same reference.
- Can't pass `this` to base constructor. No need now.

If you really want to pursue your original design, IMHO it's worth keeping in mind that **the constructor already has the `this` reference**. Remember, `this` is the same object, no matter which class in the inheritance hierarchy the code exists.

That means a "better" way to do it but still following your original idea would look like this:

```cs
abstract class Animal
{
    public Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; }

    public Animal()
    {
        KingOfTheJungle = (this as Lion) ?? KingOfTheJungle;
    }
}
```

This still has all but the last problem I mention above though. I would not implement it this way.

You mention that the jungle only ever has one `Lion`. This further suggests that you should make the `Lion` class a singleton. That would look something like this:

```cs
abstract class Animal
{
    public static Lion KingOfTheJungle { get; } = Lion.Instance

    public Animal()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Lion : Animal
{
    public static Lion Instance { get; } = new Lion();

    private Lion() { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer. I considered the idea of a `static Lion KingOfTheJungle`, but in my case I can have multiple Jungles, each with its own King. So unfortunately this solution cannot be used in my case.

Comment: Actually I have no class `Jungle` in my design (which btw has to do with enumerables and sorters instead of animals). A jungle is defined by the King, who holds the properties of the Jungle. It is not a great design now that I am thinking of it!

Comment: _"I have no class Jungle in my design"_ -- that sounds like a problem. Your type hierarchy should do a reasonable job of modeling your actual problem domain. If you have the concept of a jungle, and there can be more than one such jungle, and yet your type hierarchy doesn't reflect that, you will probably want to reconsider that. Otherwise, the problems I list above will get in the way of you keeping each animal in the correct jungle.